# How can I overlay a lightning bolt on a custom battery charging image in a fragment?

Tags: android, image-processing

I have an app that runs fullscreen, but needs to show the battery status. (It's for a fleet of rooted B&N Nooks, all eInk, Android 2.1, but with compatibility library.)

I'm running a fragment that has the battery icon in it. All of that works properly... it's displayed, it measures the right current voltage, and so. No issues there.

I want to overlay a "charging" lightning bolt, as is common, to indicate when the device is plugged in. Currently I have 16 PNGs with the battery in various states of charge and select between them with a big if statement. Meh, I only run it once every ten seconds, I'm not worried about performance there.

What I would like to do is have ONE lightning bolt image and just XOR it with the current battery image. That would give me the correct black and white portions as I go. So the question is how can I XOR one image with another?

The 'admit defeat' alternative is I could double the set of PNGs I have... one with charging bolt and one without. That would be sad though.

Comment: Looking at other tools that modify custom roms, it appears the system approach IS to generate two sets of graphics, one with a charging symbol, and one without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to reverse an image pixels by pixels https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/image-processing-invert-image-on-the-fly/

From this you could loop through both images, reverse the pixels on image A from the non-transparent pixels on image B. It should give you the effect you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what language you are writing in but I think you need to use z-index in your CSS to layer images. Check out this page, he does a pretty good job of explaining it. [what no one told you about z-index](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)

Comment: I'm aware of CSS and z-index, and while Android does support z indexing, the article linked is related to web page layout and not Android programming.